# BizTalk2013Beta WCF-WebHttp Adapter problems

Tags: adapter, biztalk

I installed new version of BizTalk2013Beta. 
When trying to add receive location or send port which use WCF-WebHttp adapter I get this error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn)

How to fix it?

Comment: I checked other adapters and they work fine.

Comment: Restarting the Windows Management Instrumentation service might work.

Comment: Tried, but problem still persists.

Comment: I reckon you have also installed the Microsoft Biztalk Adapter Pack? My next option would be doing a repair on the Biztalk installation.

Comment: Solved problem using BizTalk WCF Service Publishing Wizard. Wizard can be started from Start->Programs->Biztalk...